# Return Index Position Where First Corresponding Cell Value is Blank - Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

I have two rows side by side in Excel and I want to return the index location (top row) where the first cell in the bottom row has a blank value.  In this example, the index cell would be 9.

I've tried match is blank and index match without luck.  Any help would be appreciate.

```
=INDEX(O3:AE3,MATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK(O3:AE3),0))
```

Comment: Enter this as an array formula (done by hitting CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER). It will return the index of the first blank on that row/column.

=MATCH(TRUE,ISBLANK(A1:H1),0)

Comment: I've tried that but I'm still getting an NA even after I use the array formula

Comment: You are looking for a `TRUE` match, not `FALSE`. Also, `MATCH` will return an index of the first true within the array. If your data is consecutive as you show, there is no need for an `INDEX` at the front. If `ISBLANK` is not giving you any result, there simply aren't any true empty cells.

Comment: So how can I return the value of 9?

Comment: The answer is given by @Bilal

Comment: Unfortunately not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this

```
=MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(O3:AE3="",0),0)
```

Answer (score -1):

Or this one,

```
=MATCH(9^9,O3:AE3)+1
```